# Color by factor in 3D scatter plot returns error "argument X matches multiple formal arguments"

Tags: r, parameter-passing, scatter3d

I am simply trying to 'color by factor' in a 3D scatterplot, but get the error that the `col=` argument "matches multiple formal arguments".

From others questions and answers, I understand that it has to do with "passing over arguments" between function... But I am afraid my (sparse) level of R skills, means that I simply don't understand what that means (where am I doing that....?), or how to get around it?

Here is the code:

```
samples3d <-as.data.frame(aggmyxo_rare_NMDS$points) # sample scores

samples3d$pcolor[meta$E.nr.==1] <- "yellow"
samples3d$pcolor[meta$E.nr.==2] <- "orange"
samples3d$pcolor[meta$E.nr.==3] <- "red"
samples3d$pcolor[meta$E.nr.==4] <- "purpul"
samples3d$pcolor[meta$E.nr.==5] <- "blue"
samples3d$pcolor[meta$E.nr.==6] <- "darkblue"
samples3d$pcolor[meta$E.nr.==7] <- "green"
samples3d$pcolor[meta$E.nr.==8] <- "darkgreen"
with(samples3d, {
  s3d <- scatterplot3d(MDS1, MDS2, MDS3,pch = ifelse(meta$op.closed=="cl",22,21), col= pcolor, type="h",lty.hplot=2, scale.y=.75)
                       } )
```

This script is produced by following this excellent [guide](https://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-fancy-with-3-d-scatterplots/) on r-bloggers.

I tried all sorts of `col= factor(pcolor)`, `col= Meta$E.nr.` etc. but all gives the same error.

I also tried like this:

```
s3d <- scatterplot3d(samples3d$MDS1, samples3d$MDS2, samples3d$MDS3,  col= factor(samples3d$pcolor), type= "h", col.axis = "black",
              col.grid = "grey", main = "", pch = ifelse(meta$op.closed=="cl",22,21))
```

Thinking that in this way, I might get around "embedding" functions into functions (if that is the problem...). But no, same error.

So I apologies for asking a question which has in varies forms already been  answered, but can someone perhaps be kind to help me understand exactly the "point" of this error, and how to correct it in my specific case? I would highly appreciate it.

Best wishes,
Mathilde

Comment: You need to spell it out. col matches the arguments color, col.grid, col.lab, and col.axis. R doesn't know which argument you want.

Comment: Hahaha OMG so simple! THANK YOU!! - yep it works (when I spell "purple" correct ;)